# ASP.NET page_init event?

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.NET 3.5 and i used earlier 1.1 i am having difficulty to find where can i attach/declare the page init event ?

In 1.1 there was auto generated code which used to have initialization code. Where we can add the page init method. So i am confused please help.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Just declare this in your code behind:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
```

Comment: But for event attachment we need to do something like page.OnInit += evnetHnaglerName(Sender, EventArgs) where is that declared ... ? that is where i am more confused.

Comment: no, because you are overriding the method.  This is all taken care of for you.

Comment: It's not like 1.1 where you can see the code.  They've hidden a lot of it in the other part of the partial class.

Comment: @Anil Namde - have a look at my answer, might help your confusion.

Answer (score 62):

ASP.NET 2.0 changed the default designing/compilation model.

By default **AutoEventWireup** is set to true, which instructs compiler to automatically
attach event handlers from the code behind using naming
convention, so when you write:

```
protected void Page_Load(...)
{

}
```

it automatically puts this code in behind the scenes:

```
this.Load += new EventHandler(this.Page_Load)
```

This was previously done by **InitialiseComponent()** (i believe).

Nonetheless, the answer is to write the code yourself:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do the bartman
}
```

Comment: The only problem is that there is no autocomplete available on this. You have to know exact syntax of the event handler.

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to bind the event. Just create an event handler for it, and it will be bound automaticlaly:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For those using asp/vb.net you need to declare in code behind as:
Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

Answer (score 0):

you can add the page_init method in page's CS file. For example, if you have Default.aspx you can put the method in Default.aspx.cs

When you create a page in VS you will have the Page_Load method created for you. You can put your page_init code & other code for the page int the CS file.

**PS: If you use VB as the server side code, you will have to put it in the VB file**

Answer (score 0):

It is no different in ASP.NET 3.5 - there is a code-behind page where you can declare/attach the `OnInit` event.

To see the code behind, right click on the file in the solution explorer and select `View code`.

Answer (score 0):

just add yourself with the signature

```
protected void Page_Init() 
{
    //
}
```